# XML file is not getting imported into web application during replay with load runner 12.1

Tags: xml, import, loadrunner

While recording the script from loadrunner, I am able to import the xml file into web application but during replay of the same script the xml file is not getting imported into the web application. i have placed the xml file in the script folder as well. Please find the script which is generated as below during recording:

```
lr_think_time(27);

web_submit_data("ImportFileInBackground", 
    "Action=http://muctsa1047.eu.infineon.com:88/req/Import/ImportFileInBackground", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "EncType=multipart/form-data", 
    "RecContentType=application/json", 
    "Referer=http://muctsa1047.eu.infineon.com:88/import", 
    "Snapshot=t24.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=uploadFile", "Value=1comps3params.xml", "File=Yes", ENDITEM,LAST);
```

**Note:** I have recorded this script in `VUser_init.c`

I have even added the xml file to the extra files folder present in the script tree hierarchy.

[Image where file is added to the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayc6S.png)

Please help me how to overcome this problem.

Comment: Did you get an error or is the file just not uploaded without an error?

Comment: According to the docs you need to use ````FilePath=1comps3params.xml```` instead of ````Value=1comps3params.xml````

Comment: @buzzy : i did not got any error , just the file did not got uploaded

Comment: after adding FilePath=1comps3params.xml instead of Value=1comps3params.xml, if i am replaying it , vu script is not getting complied, it is saying unable to find "Value"

Comment: Can you check the example in the documentation please.